# Can Scala classes be modified after creation?

Tags: scala

Specifically I was thinking about equivalent functionality to 6.3 here:

http://www.siafoo.net/article/52

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala is a static language and thus all code should exists at compile time. However, you can simulate the python feature using the [*Pimp-My-Library*](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) approach to add methods to existing class, without modifying the class itself. However, you cannot change an existing method. Example:

```
class Foo( val i: Int )

class RichFoo( f: Foo ) {
  def prettyPrint = "Foo(" + i + ")"
}

implicit def enrichFoo( f: Foo ) = new RichFoo(f)

val foo = new Foo( 667 )

println( foo.prettyPrint ) // Outputs "Foo(667)"
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```
class Class {
  var method = () => println("Hey, a method (actually, a function bound to a var)")
}

val instance = new Class()
instance.method()
// Hey, a method (actually, a function bound to a var)

val new_method = () => println("New function")
instance.method = new_method

instance.method()
// New function
```

Methods themselves cannot be changed after the instance has been created.